# How to write annotation processors for kotlin/native?

Tags: kotlin, annotations, kotlin-native, kotlin-multiplatform

Is it possible to write our annotation processors in kotlin/ native or kotlin multiplatform modules? If so, then how?  I found this tutorial for kotlin: https://github.com/osamarao/ViewModelAnnotationsKt
But I am not sure how to implement the same in kotlin/ native.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently (as of Kotlin 1.3) not possible. With Kotlin/JVM, annotation processors work on top of the Java compiler API. With Kotlin/Native, the Java compiler API is not used as part of the compilation process, and there is no equivalent that can be used instead.